# Unison on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, synchronization, unison

Very simple task at hand here: using unison in a star topology in order to synchronize `/home` folders across multiple servers. So, for `~/.unison/default.prf` on each box...

Hub:

```
root = 
root = ssh://spoke1/

path = current

ignore = Name .bash*
ignore = Path .cahce
ignore = Path .dbus
ignore = Name .fehbg
ignore = Path .fluxbox
ignore = Name .profile
ignore = Path .ssh
ignore = Path .vnc
ignore = Name .Xauthority
ignore = Name .xsession-errors
```

and Spoke1:

```
root = 
root = ssh://hub/

path = current

ignore = Name .bash*
ignore = Path .cahce
ignore = Path .dbus
ignore = Name .fehbg
ignore = Path .fluxbox
ignore = Name .profile
ignore = Path .ssh
ignore = Path .vnc
ignore = Name .Xauthority
ignore = Name .xsession-errors
```

Running unison with the `testServer` flag works:

```
user1@hub:~$ unison -testServer
Contacting server...
Connected [//hub//home/user1 -> //spoke1//home/user1]
```

But when I run unison plain, it keeps complaining:

```
Warning: No archive files were found for these roots, whose canonical names are:
    /home/user1
    //spoke1//home/user1
```

Even when I've altered the user's folder. I've tried it both directions and even tried setting `UNISONLOCALHOSTNAME`, but nothing seems to make a difference. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Only your Spoke1 machine should have a `~/.unison/default.prf`. And in that profile you need to specify two roots: the path on the current machine to synchronize, and the path on the remote machine. Your `~/.unison/default.prf` should look something closer to this:

```
root = /home/user1
root = ssh://user1@spoke//home/user1

ignore = Name .bash*
...
```

You don't need the `path = current` line. That is only if you want to specify certain directories to sync (having the line `path = Desktop` would sync *only* the directory `/home/user1/Desktop`). Since you want to sync your entire home directory, this is not necessary.

Also, check your spelling of `cache` :)